# stm32 generate PWM signal with multiple channels

Tags: stm32, pwm, channel, cubemx

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
TIM3->CCR1 =25000;
```

[image]

I'm trying to set 2 pins to the same PWM signal at the same time.
However, it doesn't work. Only 1 pin (channel 1) has PWM output and the 2nd pin (channe 2) has empty output.

Comment: Please add the image to the question. Third-party links are discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Every channel has its own register CCR

You only set one, the second one has the default value - 0 - and the duty ratio of the generated PWM signal is zero or 100% depending on the other registers settings.

add:

```
TIM3->CCR2 = /*your value here*/;
```

and it should work

Comment: And I would set both CCR registers *before* starting the timer.

Answer (score 0):

try with these commands
__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, value);
__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, value);